# why did kubuntu 20.04lts stop my sony viao wireless connection

Tags: networking, kubuntu, vaio

My son has a Sony Vaio that is running Kubuntu 20.04 lts. The wifi connection stopped working on the Vaio when we installed ubuntu 19. I had hoped that kubuntu would resolve the issue but never did. It was not a big deal until now. I researched and some said they had luck with a fresh install but no such luck here. Also there is no slider or button on this vaio that controlls the wifi. I had to use jpegs because there I could not copy and paste the results of all of the things I thought would help. I ran lspci, sudo lshw -C network, and lsmod (last 2 images). [image: lspci][image: lshw -C network][image: lsmod 1][image: lsmod 2]

I am not sure what else you might need. Again sorry for images and not code. I was kind of my option.

Comment: There is not such version as 19. An actual version number is a good place to start. Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question so everyone can easily read it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: I am not able to remember the exact ubuntu version we started with. I was only able to remember that it was 19 something. I am not able to copy and paste. My son needs his laptop for work and had to take it. I am trying to solve the issue the best with what I have. My plan was to copy and paste but he had no choice but to take it with him. Sorry if I sound snappy. I promise that is not the intention.

Comment: I am going to look into the installing the broadcom drivers link. I am hoping to have him home sometime today and will give this a try. I hope it works. Thank you for the lead. I will post the results either way.